# Rails Carrierwave - compress file in specific conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I'm using `Carrierwave` and `carrierwave-base64` for file upload on **Amazon S3**.

How can I compress uploaded files only if they are over `xMB`. Files are in jpeg, png and jpg formats as images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `before :store` hook. For example:

```
before :store, :compress_file

def compress_file(_file)
  file_size = (File.size(file.path).to_f / 2**20)
  if file_size > x
    # compress file
  end
end
```

Comment: yes, I was searching something like that. Big thanks. One more thing, is this going to Uploader or somewhere else?

Comment: You have to put this is the uploader